# Spring Integration: How to filter specific headers - only possible with header mapper?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In spring integration you can set the properties `mapped-request-headers`, `mapped-response-headers` and `header-mapper` in an `outbound-gateway`.

My target is to filter out specific headers, so I need some kind of **blacklist**. But the first two attributes are **whitelists**. I can either say `mapped-request-headers="*"`, then every header will be passed, or I can put some specific headers, but then only these headers will be passed. But that's not what I want.

I could somehow overwrite the header mapper and add this bean to the `header-mapper` attribute, but is this the way of doing this? (I wonder why headers can be whitelisted but not blacklisted). Isn't there some functionality to set "filter spring added headers" and "pass manually added headers" or something?

Comment: I think `header-filter ` might help you.You can get rid of all the headers that you don't want by using `header-filter` . You can configure it like `<int:header-filter  header-names="accept-encoding"/>` before you call your rest service. I am assuming that you are using `http:outbound-gateway` or `adapter` to call the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what Spring Integration version you are using, or the type of endpoint you are using.

Since version 4.3, mappers that extend from `AbstractHeaderMapper` (AMQP, SOAP, XMPP) now support negated headers `"!foo,!bar,baz*"`.

If you are not using one of these protocols, you can use a header filter upstream of the endpoint (for outbound) or right after the endpoint (inbound).

For the HTTP header mapper (`DefaultHttpHeaderMapper`) you can wire in a custom bean of that type where you add any standard headers you wish to exclude via the `excludedOutboundStandardRequestHeaderNames` and `excludedInboundStandardResponseHeaderNames` properties.